# Javascript Validate Date script would not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have run into an error where my script would not work on my HTML file. This script is used to ensure that the input submitted for date would not be accepted if the date is greater than today. However, when I transfer my script over to another HTML file, it works. It just doesn't work on this single HTML file.

```js
function checkform() {
  answ = validateDate(document.getElementById("doa").value);
  if (answ == false) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }

}

function validateDate(doa) {
  var d = new Date(doa);
  var n = new Date();
  if (d >= n) {
    alert("Date cannot be greater than today.");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```css
.welcome {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Calibri;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.rating {
  text-align: center;
}

.particulars {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}

.form {
  margin-left: 10%;
}

hr {
  border-color: #F172A1;
}

.column {
  background-color: #E64398;
  color: white;
}

.columnrating {
  background-color: #F172A1;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.columnrating2 {
  background-color: #A1C3D1;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.row {
  background-color: #F172A1;
  color: white;
}

.row2 {
  background-color: #779ecb;
  color: white;
}

.rowrating2 {
  background-color: #F7EFD7;
  text-align: center;
}

.buttons {
  background-color: #A1C3D1;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

table {
  font-family: Calibri;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Customer Feedback Survey</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="furpaws.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!--Header-->
  <table bgcolor="#F172A1" height="10%" width="100%" class="tab" />
  <tr>
    <td width="1%" rowspan="2" height="5%" align="center" valign="middle">
      <a class="bleft"><img src="webpublogo.png" height="13%" /></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <!--End of Header-->

  <br/>

  <!--Caption and Info-->
  <h2 align="center">Customer Feedback Survey</h2>
  <hr>
  <p class="particulars">
    Please fill in the form<br> Required fields are marked with an asterisk *<br>
  </p>
  <hr>
  <!--End of Caption and Info-->
  <br>

  <!--Particulars-->
  <table class="form">
    <form action="feedbackresult.html" onsubmit="return checkForm()">
      <tr>
        <td><label for="firstname">First Name: </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="first" id="firstname"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label for="lastname">Last Name: </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="last" id="lastname"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label for="mobileNo">Handphone No:* </label></td>
        <td><input type="tel" name="hpno" id="mobileNo" placeholder="e.g 91234567" maxlength="8" minlength="8" required></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label for="doa">Date of Appointment:* </label></td>
        <td><input type="date" name="date" id="doa" min="2000-01-01" required></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <!--End of Particulars-->

  <br/>

  <!--Survey-->
  <table align="center" border="0" width="80%" height="50%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <col width="3%">
    <col width="0.4%">
    <col width="0.4%">
    <col width="0.4%">
    <col width="0.4%">
    <col width="0.4%">
    <tr>
      <td class="column" style="text-align:center"> Please rate the following areas:</td>
      <td class="columnrating2">Very Poor</td>
      <td class="columnrating">Poor</td>
      <td class="columnrating2">Fair</td>
      <td class="columnrating">Good</td>
      <td class="columnrating2">Very Good</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="row2">*Grooming Services</td>
      <td class="rowrating2"><input type="radio" name="groomingServices" id="veryPoor" required></td>
      <td class="rowrating2"><input type="radio" name="groomingServices" id="Poor"></td>
      <td class="rowrating2"><input type="radio" name="groomingServices" id="fair"></td>
      <td class="rowrating2"><input type="radio" name="groomingServices" id="good"></td>
      <td class="rowrating2"><input type="radio" name="groomingServices" id="veryGood"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="row">*Customer Service</td>
      <td class="rowrating2"><input type="radio" name="customerService" id="veryPoor" required></td>
      <td class="rowrating2"><input type="radio" name="customerService" id="Poor"></td>
      <td class="rowrating2"><input type="radio" name="customerService" id="fair"></td>
      <td class="rowrating2"><input type="radio" name="customerService" id="good"></td>
      <td class="rowrating2"><input type="radio" name="customerService" id="veryGood"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="row2">*Hospitality of your pets</td>
      <td class="rowrating2"><input type="radio" name="hospitality" id="veryPoor" required></td>
      <td class="rowrating2"><input type="radio" name="hospitality" id="Poor"></td>
      <td class="rowrating2"><input type="radio" name="hospitality" id="fair"></td>
      <td class="rowrating2"><input type="radio" name="hospitality" id="good"></td>
      <td class="rowrating2"><input type="radio" name="hospitality" id="veryGood"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="row">*Groomers were polite</td>
      <td class="rowrating2"><input type="radio" name="groomers" id="veryPoor" required></td>
      <td class="rowrating2"><input type="radio" name="groomers" id="Poor"></td>
      <td class="rowrating2"><input type="radio" name="groomers" id="fair"></td>
      <td class="rowrating2"><input type="radio" name="groomers" id="good"></td>
      <td class="rowrating2"><input type="radio" name="groomers" id="veryGood"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="row2">*Cleanliness of environment</td>
      <td class="rowrating2"><input type="radio" name="environment" id="veryPoor" required></td>
      <td class="rowrating2"><input type="radio" name="environment" id="Poor"></td>
      <td class="rowrating2"><input type="radio" name="environment" id="fair"></td>
      <td class="rowrating2"><input type="radio" name="environment" id="good"></td>
      <td class="rowrating2"><input type="radio" name="environment" id="veryGood"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="row">&nbsp;Remarks</td>
      <td colspan="6" class="rowrating2"><textarea style="vertical-align:top;"> </textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6" align="center">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="buttons">
      </td>
    </tr>
    </form>
  </table>
  <!--End of Survey-->
  <br/>
  <br/>
</body>
```

I would love to find out what went wrong with my HTML file that caused the script to not work. Thank you.

Regards,
Mark

Comment: Could you properly format your code please. that would help . other than that you are missing a `>` at the end of your steelsheet (see `</style`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just closed the tag wrongly. it should be like this:

```
<!--Particulars-->
<form action="feedbackresult.html" onsubmit="return checkForm()">
    <table class="form">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="firstname">First Name: </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="first" id="firstname">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="lastname">Last Name: </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="last" id="lastname">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="mobileNo">Handphone No:* </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="tel" name="hpno" id="mobileNo" placeholder="e.g 91234567" maxlength="8" minlength="8" required="">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="doa">Date of Appointment:* </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="date" name="date" id="doa" min="2000-01-01" required="">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! Helped save alot of my time